# Overload the ""_something operator on identifiers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20

Is possible, in `C++`, to overload the `""_something` operator for function identifiers or callables
in order to make it have custom behaviour?

I recently saw something similar in [this cppcon video](https://youtu.be/-qAXShy1xiE?t=1240), where the presenter is exposing how to build a unit test framework using modules, zero macros... but I am not understanding well how the `""_test` is possible, or how `C++` understands that for that callable should perform such an action defined in the body of the operator overloading implementation.

```
template <typename T>
auto "some_name"_test(T a, T b);
```

Can someone explain the details behind this?

Comment: Look up *user-defined literals*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat already did it at `cppreference`. After that, I opened the question

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Are you asking how `"foo"_test = []{};` in the video works? The UDL `_test` returns a class with an overloaded `operator=`, that does something with the lambda passed to it.

Comment: @yes,  that's what I was trying to ask

Comment: what is the difficult part of understand the question? It any other place in the world, but in a SO C++ question this could happen... Seriously isn't clear that is just asking how the UDL operator works?

Comment: @NotJungler'sFault: "*Seriously isn't clear that is just asking how the UDL operator works?*" No, it isn't. As evidenced by the fact that my answer *doesn't* explain "how the UDL operator works", yet the OP seems largely satisfied with it. HolyBlackCat's question is entirely valid.

Comment: @NotJungler'sFault that's not legit. Question could be not understandable in some ways or pespectives, there's no problem in clarifying whatever is necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UDL `operator ""` is just a function call. Functions can return anything. They can, for example, return an object type which has an overloaded `operator()`, and is therefore callable. They can return an object type with an overloaded `operator=`, and is therefore assignable. Etc.

It's not about how you overload the UDL operator; it's about what your overload *returns*.

Comment: A minimal example on `It's not about how you overload the UDL operator; it's about what your overload returns.` would be fine